# add two navigation controller to one Tab bar Item

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ipad

I want 2 navigation Controller to be attached to one Tab bar item.

Basically the idea is to have 2 views on a single tab Item and there should be a navigation bar to push and pop the screens. (same like settings application in iPad).

edited======

It will look like on left hand side there is a View with its own navigation Controller and on right hand side there is another View with its own navigation controller(or some other UI) to achieve the Push Pop stuff.

I know how to attach 1 navigation Controller to one Tab bar Item.

**Edited For ModalView Issue**:-
 by implementing conmulligan code everything works property. But if I try to display some ModalViewController in lansdscape mode and when I try to close this ModalView the FirstViewController navigationbar becomes portrait(along with its View) and SecondViewController NavigationBar remains landscape(at it should be). This happens only in Device not in simulator.

Below is my Code of presenting the ModalViewController.

```
ModalTableViewController *modalTableViewController = [[ModalTableViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ModalTableViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
UINavigationController *localNavigationViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:modalTableViewController];
localNavigationViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentModalViewController:localNavigationViewController animated:YES];
[modalTableViewController release];
[localNavigationViewController release];
```

For Dismising the ModalViewCntroller I do it as below:-

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Waiting for your replies.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to create a `UIViewController` subclass that contains two navigation controllers and add that to the `UITabBarController`. Here's how you'd create and layout the navigation controllers in the `UIViewController`'s `-viewDidLoad` method:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *firstNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
[firstViewController release];

SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *secondNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
[secondViewController release];

firstNavigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 320.f, self.view.frame.size.height);
firstNavigationController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

secondNavigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(321.f, 0.f, self.view.frame.size.width - 321.f, self.view.frame.size.height);
secondNavigationController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
                                                   UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

[self.view addSubview:firstNavigationController.view];
[self.view addSubview:secondNavigationController.view];
```

This is more or less how the `UISplitViewController` works under the hood.

**Edit:** you might need to add the following code to make sure it lays out properly:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [firstNavigationController viewWillAppear:animated];
    [secondNavigationController viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [firstNavigationController viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [secondNavigationController viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [firstNavigationController viewDidAppear:animated];
    [secondNavigationController viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [firstNavigationController viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [secondNavigationController viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: - thanks for your reply. From your code if I try to start the app in landscape mode than I am not able to see both the view. I am able to see only one View that is secondViewController. Can you help me on this.

Comment: Hi @Ekra, that's strange, it works for me. Try adding the extra code above to your `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: - thanks for your reply. I have some issue with displaying ModalView which I have explained above. Please have a look on it. Waiting for your reply.