# iPad : two-stage method implementation

Tags: iphone, ipad, rotation, orientation, stage

here is my problem, I hope someone can help me.

My iPad app is made like this : I have several viewControllers added as tabs in a tabBarController added to window in my appDelegate. In each of these viewControllers I got two navigationControllers with one viewController in.

- Appdelegate

  - TabBarController

    - viewController

      - navigationController

        - viewController
      - navigationController

        - viewController
    - viewController

      - navigationController

        - viewController
      - navigationController

        - viewController

Everything work fine in simulator but when I run it on device I got this warning :

```
Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations.
```

It only happen when I run it on a device in landscape mode. The first navigationController of the default view shown by the tabBarController take all the screen width (not important here but it's to explain that this warning makes my layout going crazy). In portrait nothing is traced in the console.

I read many things about this message but I can't find any solution to make it go away.
I'm sure it's a story of shouldAutoRotate or something like this.
I also notice that if i remove the tabBarController and simply add my first viewController to window, the message is not shown.

Very strange... please help :)

Comment: Just a question: how did you add two different navigation controllers to a single view controller? What kind of UI are you designing? I bet this could be the problem ...

Comment: My goal was to create a simple UI like the settings app on iPad. [This post inspired me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259416/add-two-navigation-controller-to-one-tab-bar-item/5282107#5282107)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should rely on the standard `UISplitViewController` available under iPad. This controller is what is used under the Settings app and various other apps.

If you do not feel comfortable with such a tool, you can take a look at the [APSplitViewController](https://github.com/slatvick/APSplitViewController) plugin developed by slatvick on GitHub. This could solve a lot of your problems, I hope.

#### Edit

Googling about this issue, I found out that this warning appears when you create a wrong hierarchy of view controllers. In this case, you are pushing two navigation controllers inside a view controller, even if a view controller is not meant to contain different navigation controller. Probably there could be a problem related on how you send up to the parent view controller methods like `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillLoad:` etc. You should try to understand if you are passing all these call correctly to the parent view controller from the inner navigation controllers.

Comment: Yeah I know but the standard UISplitViewcontroller have a private API method setHidesMasterViewInPortrait which makes what I wanted to do. It would be more simple with it... I'll try with APSplitViewController thanks !

Comment: Let me know if this works. This plugin does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: I think he got problems with orientation to. The sample is forced to run in portrait... and if I force it in landscape, the UI is broken and I got this log (angain...) `Using two-stage rotation animation. To use the smoother single-stage animation, this application must remove two-stage method implementations`.

Comment: But if you look at the documentation and/or screenshot you can see that it's meant to work with both orientations. What code do you use to "force" it in landscape mode?

Comment: Yeah after you launch it you can turn it into landscape but by default the app is launched in portrait. To get the log message I disable portrait orientations in project settings (under Supported Device Orientation).

Comment: By the way: are you only getting a warning or something does not work here?

Comment: I edited the answer with some more hints. Hope this helps, otherwise I cannot solve your problem right now, I think.

Comment: The UI is well broken... if it only was a warning

Comment: Ok thanks... For the moment I'll give up and use the real splitViewController. I'll try later with more time to loose ;)

Comment: Please, check my edited answer. It could probably be a problem related to a wrong propagation of those calls ... good luck!

Comment: Yep I'll mark your post as an answer when I'll retry to solve my problem. Thanks anyway