# Custom SplitView: Added 2 NavigationController(called master,detail) in 1 ViewController but master view controller button is not clickable

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4.5

It seems that only that view button is clickable which is added last.

```
 self.splitViewController = [[[ViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; 
 self.splitViewController.delegate = self;

 ViewController *mainViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

 ViewController *detailedViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];

 UINavigationController *mainViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
 mainViewNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

 UINavigationController *detailedViewNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
 detailedViewNavigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

 [mainViewNavigationController pushViewController:mainViewController animated:YES];
 [self.splitViewController.view addSubview:mainViewNavigationController.view];

 [detailedViewNavigationController pushViewController:detailedViewController animated:YES];
 [self.splitViewController.view addSubview:detailedViewNavigationController.view];
```

Comment: "button is unclickable" - what button are you talking about?

Comment: Added UIButton in mainViewController as well in detailViewController.But click event of mainViewController is not working. Both button are same. Issue is with container the way i am adding not with Button.

Comment: I see. the reason I'm asking is that you added 2 controllers and you see both of them (according to buttons)

Comment: this looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259416/add-two-navigation-controller-to-one-tab-bar-item

Comment: After doing this, It is going into infinite loop. - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { 
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [firstNavigationController viewWillAppear:animated];
    [secondNavigationController viewWillAppear:animated];
}